# Linq to SQL - Order By related Table using a Where Clause

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have two related tables lets say:

Table Products (Main Table)

- ID
- Name
- Type

Table Parts (Child of Products, contains detailled Information)

- ID
- ProductID
- PartName
- PartValue

I would like to get Products ordered by the value of a specific part (e.G. Engine)

I came up with the following:

```
// Code to construct a query to get all desired products
products = products.OrderBy(c => c.Parts.Where(d => d.PartName == "Engine").Select(d => d.Value).FirstOrDefault());
```

This works but is too slow. Can I improve the query or will I have to redsign my database so I won't be sorting like this in the first place?

Generated SQL-Query:

```
SELECT 
    [Project3].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project3].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project2].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
            (SELECT TOP (1) 
                [Extent2].[PartValue] AS [PartValue]
                FROM [dbo].[Parts] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ProductID]) AND (N'Engine' = [Extent2].[PartName])) AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE (1 = [Extent1].[Type])
        )  AS [Project2]
    )  AS [Project3]
    ORDER BY [Project3].[C1] ASC
```

Comment: Is it EF  query? If yes - can you please add  the generated sql?

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ but is a pure database question. Use your sql-profiler and check the execution plan, then you know which indexes are lacking. But yes, if possible, couldn't you add the `EngineValue` as a column in the `Products` table. Of course that would be much more efficient.

Comment: I would try rewriting it as a join

Comment: @GuruStron: Sure, I have updated my question

Comment: that looks horrendous, try using a join

Comment: It's slow because you're sorting on a non-indexed field. What data do you actually need? Just the `Id` and `Name`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I could, but I'm hesitant since I might have other "Sorting-Parts" in the future like "Tires" or "Windshield" and would like to stay flexible

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth ID of the product (for Identification) and PartValues (of several parts for the GUI)

Comment: @Hamster: You could add a flexible `SortingValue` column. Then decide wherever you create the record(stored-procedure) what value comes there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try a join, it would be a bit like this:

```
        Products
        .Join(Parts, pd => pd.ID, pt => pt.ProductID, (pd, pt) => new { pd.Name, pt.PartName, pt.PartValue })
        .Where(x => x.PartName == "Engine")
        .OrderBy(x => x.PartValue);
```

This would result in a single select statement without the inner selects from before

Comment: Thank you, I tried to test the code, but I don't have a naviagtion property for pt.ProductID.
It does not look like You can create a join without navigational properties and you cannot add them on exitsing tables in Entity Framework